# Neural Network OCR - using probability to determine touching symbols?

Tags: neural-network, ocr

Now I use some neural network for OCR and it produces output symbol and some probability for it. Also I have algorithm to split touching characters.

I expected to use probability to decide when to apply splitting. 
But now I cannot do this because my network sometimes gives probability for touching characters higher then for normal characters.

Also I cannot understand what happened even after splitting - sometimes normal symbol can be split into two another symbols that both can be recognized with higher probability that initial symbol.

So I need to decide what to do. The question is 
can Neural Network at least in theory provide reliable probability for OCR in this sense? 
If it is possible then what should I try to do? Should I try to process current output or train network more or choose another network?

Any kind of help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good and should eventually work given enough training data and given that you remove enough bugs from your preprocessing, splitting, training, etc.

Make sure that you split in the training set (prior to training) exactly the same way that you split the digits when you test them.

But note that Machine Learning produces algorithms that are correct within some accuracy, so you will always find instances that fail. The question is how good is your overall test performance (e.g. % correct digits), and how to increase this to the level that your application requires.

> The question is can Neural Network at least in theory provide reliable
>   probability for OCR in this sense?

Yes

> If it is possible then what should I try to do?  Should I try to
>   process current output or train network more or choose another
>   network?

all of the above until it works! Training size is one of the key factors, and as you grow your training size you can grow your network to improve accuracy.

Comment: Current situation is that neural network gives 0.99 probability to some combinations, like it thinks that touching 'fl' is 'n' with probability 0.994786739